# Is it possible to estimate effects using Bayesian modelling after matching?

Tags: bayesian, causality, matching, brms

I am following [Greifer 2023][1] to estimate the effect size after (genetic) matching, where I am using bootstrapping to estimate the confidence intervals. Since I have a hierarchical setup with repeat measures (harvests) from fields and fields nested within sites, a frequentist approach (using lmer) resulted in a singular variance-covariance matrix. Thus, I am exploring Bayesian options, namely the brms package. However, it does not appear possible to incorporate the matching weights when using the brm function. Is a Bayesian approach possible in this setup and if so how?

Specifically, this is the code I am trying:
(but it is not working: "Error in weighted.mean.default(p1, md1$weights) :
'x' and 'w' must have the same length")

```
boot_fun <- function(data, i) {
  boot_data <- data[i,]
  
  #Do nm mahalanobis matching with replacement
  m <- matchit(farm_type ~ 
                 perc_quality + suitability_index + Crop + travel50 + owner2 + prop_harvest_sold,
               data = boot_data,
               method = "nearest", distance = "mahalanobis", estimand = "ATT", replace = TRUE, pop.size = 1000)
  
  #Extract matched dataset
  md <- match.data(m, data = boot_data)
  
  #Fit bayesian outcome model with matching weights
  fit <- brm(yield_kj_sqrt | weights(weights)~ farm_type + perc_quality + suitability_index 
             + (1|Square.ID/Point.ID), 
             data = md)
  
  ## G-computation ##
  #Subset to treated units for ATT
  md1 <- subset(md, farm_type == 1)
  
  #Estimated potential outcomes under treatment
  p1 <- predict(fit, type = "response",
                newdata = transform(md1, farm_type = 1))
  Ep1 <- weighted.mean(p1, md1$weights)
  
  #Estimated potential outcomes under control
  p0 <- predict(fit, type = "response",
                newdata = transform(md1, farm_type = 0))
  Ep0 <- weighted.mean(p0, md1$weights)
  
  #Risk ratio (RR) - Ep1 / Ep0, 
  #change to Ep1 - Ep0 to get RD - risk difference
  return(Ep1 - Ep0)
}



  [1]: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/estimating-effects.html
```

Comment: Matching is an “outside of the model” process for which there are no unique principled ways to analyze the data.  Instead I would try to incorporate the variables matched upon directly into a model.